# How to solve index column issue in Panda while converting to json file?

Tags: json, pandas

There is a pandas dataframe as follow :

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIPLF.png)

I wanted to create a json file by using this command `df.to_json(os.path.join(path, 'test.json'))`

My desired output is

```
{"Big": {"A": "Big", "B": [["rose", 100], ["camelia", 200], ["Lily", 300]], }, "Medium": {"A": "Medium", "B": [["house", 45], ["car", 30], ["money", 56]], }}
```

Instead, the output I am having is:

```
{"A":{"0":"Big","1":"Medium",},"B":{"0":[["rose", 100], ["camelia", 200], ["Lily", 300]], "1":[[["house", 45], ["car", 30], ["money", 56]] }}
```

I also tried by taking the Column A as my index column `df=df.set_index('A')`. 
But that gives me more puzzled answer:

```
{"B":{"Big":[":[["rose", 100], ["camelia", 200], ["Lily", 300]],"Medium":[["house", 45], ["car", 30], ["money", 56]]}}
```

Can anybody help me how to solve that issue?

Comment: Instead of showing an Excel file, show your DataFrame after you read it. And a **very important** detail: Do not pass pictures. Show text content that can be easily copied. We have no time to manually rewrite the content from your picture.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you read your Excel file invoking a command like:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', skiprows=2, index_col=0, names=[None, 'A', 'B'])
```

i.e.:

- `skiprows=2` - skip 2 initial empty rows,
- `index_col=0` - set column *0* (in Excel parlance - column *A*) as the index,
- `names=...` - ignore existing column names (line 3 - nothing for index,
  *Fruit* and *Flowers* for data columns) and set column names from the
  given list.

This way the DataFrame contains:

```
        A                                         B
0     Big  [(rose:100), (camelia:200), (Lily: 300)]
1  Medium       [(house:45), (car:30), (money: 56)]
```

and just this should be the actual start of your post (instead of Excel screenshot).

To get the JSON output similar to your desired result, you can run:

```
df.set_index('A', drop=False).to_json('Output.json', orient='index')
```

The result (prettyfied for readability) is:

```
{
  "Big"   : {"A": "Big",    "B":"[(rose:100), (camelia:200), (Lily: 300)]"},
  "Medium": {"A": "Medium", "B":"[(house:45), (car:30), (money: 56)]"}
}
```

The difference is in *B* column: The whole content is a **single** string,
e.g. `"[(rose:100), (camelia:200), (Lily: 300)]"`, whereas you want
`[["rose", 100], ["camelia", 200], ["Lily", 300]]`, i.e. a list of lists.

If this detail is important, you can reformat *B* column:

```
df.B = df.B.str.extractall(r'\((?P<name>\w+) *: *(?P<num>\d+)\)')\
    .astype({'num': 'int'}).apply(list, axis=1).unstack()\
    .apply(lambda lst: lst.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)
```

and **after that** save to JSON. This time the result is just as you need.

The above conversion involves several steps, maybe a bit difficult
for inexperienced reader.
To fully comprehend how it works, execute each step separately
and then inspect results of each step.

I only add that the final *apply* of a *lambda* function (instead of
plain *list* as before) is needed if the number of matches from
*extractall* is different in particular rows.
In this case *NaN* entries must be filtered out.

Comment: Actually my target type for Column B is a list. But still workable if it is a string. So the orientation worked for me.

Comment: is there any way to plot the data frame column B (those elements are tuples) for each element in column A ? I have tried by extracting B column from the original data set and then plotted B (by using tuple plotting), but for that I have to use a FOR loop which creates plots for each element of column B in different windows. I am trying to plot it in a one window with the title as column A elements.

Comment: This is rather material for another question. It is a bad habit to "gradually extend" the initial question.

Comment: Already asked in a separate and more understandable way. Hope that might work. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801619/how-to-plot-a-bunch-of-list-which-contains-tuples-in-a-single-window