# How to plot a bunch of list which contains tuples in a single window?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe with only two columns named "Movies" and "Reviews".

```
    Movie                        Review
0  Titanic       [(public:90), (critics:40)]
1  LOR           [(public:80), (critics:60)]
```

To plot the "Review" for **each** Movie, I used the following code

```
movie_column = df['Movies']
review_column = df['Review']
for i in range (len(movie_column)):
     my_list = [(elem1, elem2) for elem1, elem2 in review_column[i]]
     zip(my_list)
     plt.title(str(movie_column[i]))
     to_plot = plt.scatter(*zip(*my_list))
     plt.show()
```

With this code, it prints two different plots in two different window. I wanted to make like a scatter plot so that it creates two plots in one single window.

And is it possible to create using **Seaborn**? because I could not find how to print list of tuples in Seaborn, all solutions are using matplotlib.

Comment: can you share with us  your Dataframe ?

Comment: [{'Movie': 'Titanic', 'Review': [('public', 90), ('critics', 40)]}, {'Movie': 'LOR', 'Review': [('public', 80), ('critics', 60)]}]